# Google Play App rejected because In-App-Purchasing not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games

I sent my unity app to Google Play for review but it was rejected with the reason "App contains buttons that are not working". The picture shows my menu in which you can do IAP and you can see that the prices the price texts were not loaded. That's why I think that the IAP buttons are meant by this.

However, I stored the products under Products -> In-App Products and without any typos. Is there anything else that I need to consider or do I have to store the products differently? The support team didn't give me any correct answers to my questions either. Thanks!